# Filtering out empty lists from inside a list

Tags: haskell-platform, haskell

Consider the list

```
  [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[],[2],[2,3],[],[3],[]]
```

I want to filter out all elements which are not empty lists i.e the filtered output should give me a result like:

```
  [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2],[2,3],[3]]
```

The following code fails:

```
  myfilter lst = filter(\x -> x/=[]) lst
```

with the following error for [12,3,[]]

```
   No instance for (Num [a])
  arising from the literal `3' at <interactive>:1:13
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a])
In the expression: 3
In the first argument of `myfilter', namely `[12, 3, []]'
In the expression: myfilter [12, 3, []]
```

Comment: Why does it fail? The code you provide gives a result that exactly matches the required output. Maybe you need to elaborate more on what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but as a style thing, it's generally considered good form to use `null` or `not . null` rather than `(==[])` or `(/=[])`, because it doesn't require a spurious `Eq` instance.

Comment: Yes, this would be more elegant: `myFilter = filter (not.null)`.

Answer (score 15):

Your function looks fine, but this:

```
myfilter [12, 3, []]
```

...is a type error. Lists contain values of homogeneous type, while you've put both numbers and an empty list here.

I expect that what you wanted was `[[12], [3], []]` instead.

In GHCi:

```
> myfilter [[12], [3], []]
[[12],[3]]
```

...which seems to be exactly what you wanted.

---

And for future, reference, a translation key for the error you got:

```
No instance for (Num [a])
```

This means it tried, and failed, to find an instance of `Num` for the type `[a]`. We don't expect that instance to exist, so the problem lies elsewhere.

```
arising from the literal `3' at <interactive>:1:13
```

The `Num` type class contains `fromInteger`, which is used to translate numeric literals like `3` to some specific type. So what this tells us is that it found `3` in a context where it expected something of type `[a]`, and tried to use `fromInteger` on it. This caused the "no instance" error above.

```
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a])
```

This line is nonsense. Errors caused by a missing `Num` instance are almost never caused by forgetting to write a sensible instance declaration.

```
In the expression: 3
```

This tells us the expression where the error was found. We already knew this, though, from the mention of the literal `3` earlier.

```
In the first argument of `myfilter', namely `[12, 3, []]'
```

More context for the expression with the error, and this is where we can finally spot the problem: Because of lists having homogenous type, given `12` and `3` of type `Num a => a`, and `[]` of type `[a]`, it's unified those to get `Num [a] => [a]`, causing the error. The fix in this case is what I said above, and `[[12], [3], []]` has the (correct) type `Num a => [[a]]`.

Comment: @Saket Choudhary: Happens to all of us. :] The nice thing is that once you get used to how the errors are reported, it saves you a lot of headaches in catching silly mistakes like this *before* you run the program.